# Converting UIImage to NSData with UIImageJPEGRepresentaion() and saving it to a file increases the file size in bytes

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, size, nsdata

I have a requirement in which the user can select an image from `camera roll` and my application needs to optimize the image and upload it to a server. I am using `ALAssets` library and a custom picker for the user to select a photo from `camera roll`. I am able to achieve this perfectly but have a problem with the file size getting increased.

The problem is as follows:
When the user selects a photo, of 1.7MB (That is the full size as reported by the `iOS` when I try to mail the photo), when I directly get the bytes from the `ALAssetRepresentation` of that `ALAsset` and convert it to `NSData` the size of data is 1.7MB too. But, when I get a UIImage from the `ALAssetRepresentation` using the following code..

UIImage *selImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullResolutionImage] scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:[assetRepresentation orientation]];

and converting the `UIImage` to `NSData` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` with compression quality = 1.0f, the NSData size becomes almost double the original size (3.2MB).

Shouldn't it ideally be 1.7MB only??

As expected, when I save it to a file, the file size still says 3.2MB (I checked it using xcode 4.2 by importing the sandbox app's documents folder). But the interesting thing is when I open the file with `Preview` on my mac, and check for the byte size, it says 1.7MB (was 3.2 MB) which is pretty confusing..

Please help..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve this problem finally?

Comment: I only ended up using UIImageJPEGRepresentation() with a compression quality of 0.95. The image size is reduced back to what it should be and the quality did not really decrease.

Comment: Hi @Ravi, you finally found a way to solve this?

Comment: @OmidHashemi like in my previous comment, I only ended up using UIImageJPEGRepresentation() with a compression quality of 0.95. The image size is reduced back to what it should be and the quality did not really decrease.

Comment: @Ravi Any update on this one? I am in pretty much the same situation.

Comment: I did not try this recently. I tried UIImageJPEGRepresentation() with a quality just below 1.0f  i.e 0.9f  The size is okay then and I did not really see any noticeable change in quality. So I went with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What compression quality are you specifying? Is this the same or different from what was used on the original image? If it is different, try it with the same compression factor and see if the size is the same.

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

Comment: I'm using a compression quality of 1.0 and am taking the photos from the user's camera roll/photo library. I am not sure of their compression quality but I am assuming they have a compression quality of 1.0 as well. Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: I don't have that information but I don't think you should assume what compression the photo library uses.It might say in the docs. Try using a lower value for compression Quality and see what you get.

Comment: It would reduce the size but I wanted the image at highest possible quality as they are for printing.. Thanks TOD for trying to help me out..