# NSData to UIImage back to NSData resulting length size tripled

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

I am doing a simple image file size reduction task but got this issue. When using no-loss option for JPEGs, the file size tripled then the original NSData for the image (same resolution). Any suggestion?

Here is the simple code:

```
let data = someImageData
print(data.length)
let image = UIImage(data: data)!
let newImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
print(newImageData.length)
let newImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
print(newImageData.length)
```

and output:

```
2604768  //original length
8112955  //new length if compression = 1
2588870  //new length if compression = 0.8
```

It seems I have to take the 0.8 quality loss to get the same data length. Did I miss something? Pease help.

Edit: I did some more test by converting the data to UIImage then to UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1), the length size of the new data increases every cycle. But if I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8), the length size of the new data decreases a bit (very little), however, the compound qualify loss should be a concern.

Comment: I did some search again and found this question on so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500396/converting-uiimage-to-nsdata-with-uiimagejpegrepresentaion-and-saving-it-to-a?rq=1   However, it's yet solved even after more than 4 years...

Answer (score 2):

What your code is doing is decompressing/extracting the image into memory with the line --> `let image = UIImage(data: data)!` 
and then recompressing as JPEG, with `let newImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)` with the highest quality ratio `(q=1.0)`. That’s why the image is suddenly so big.

So the moment you get your image as an UIImage from NSData, the decompression/conversion changes the size of the image.

The image's file size will actually be  8112955.

Comment: The data is from an image file (obtained through PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset) and its filesize is actually close to 2604768